# What were the sea shells for in Demolition Man?

Tags: props, demolition-man

The three shells used in the toilets even confused poor ol' Sylvester, how were they used?

Comment: I don't think we'll ever _really_ know the answer to this. It's just one of the quirky things about this movie.

Comment: In a society where people were too fastidious to have meatsex anymore, surely the seashells were controls for some kind of bidet.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6688/how-did-the-three-seashells-work-in-demolition-man

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Wikipedia article for Demolition Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demolition_Man_%28film%29):

> *By 2032, toilet paper has fallen out of use; a set of three seashells is provided in every toilet stall. Though their method of use is left unexplained in the movie, Stallone later suggested a possible method in an interview as told to him by one of the film's writers involving extraction with two and scraping with one.*

Answer (score 14):

[This](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/30865) is the page with the interview to Stallone where the question of the questions was originally answered. We all say thank you **Louis Saucedo from Dallas, Texas** for having asked it exactly that day.

Here is also a small screenshot for posterity.

[image: demolition man three seashells revealed aintitcool.com]

Comment: Then what, you just set the shitty seashells back on the shelf for the next person?

Comment: @coburne Yes, *recycle*.